# From where does the sound come from when two charged objects meet in real life?

Tags: electrostatics, acoustics, perception

I am sure all of us have played with rubbing things and producing static electricity and when I was charging my comb by rubbing it on my hair and watching it attracting a small piece of paper, I heard a very feeble noise just like an electric buzz sound. I could feel the electron "cloud" all around the comb and the paper  it I could find no reason as to why a sound should be produced. From where is that sound coming from?

Comment: My guess is that the hairs in your inner ear were being moved by the field.  The normal electric "buzz" associated with household electricity is from the changing electric field from the AC current which is different than the nearly static field around the comb.

Comment: I do not think so. It was actually a very feeble voice. Sometimes even my slippers get charged due to rubbing on the floor and when I walk, I feel the same "cloud" and also heard that sound. In that case my hair shouldn't move.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all objects around us are electrically neutral, meaning they have no excess in negative/positive charges. When we use a plastic comb on our hair, a very small amount of negative charges start accumulating on the comb, making it negatively charged. It is important to note that it is not the friction caused by combing your hair that leads to such charge accumulation, instead it is simply related to maximizing the contact surface between comb-hair, making the charge exchange more likely to occur. This is of course all in simple words.

Now as for the sounds you hear, they are called electric sparks, which results from the discharge of two initially charged objects. The electric field created by the two, ionizes the air, creating ions from air molecules, which in turn becomes a conductive channel (temporarily), this channel is necessary for the discharge (exchange of charges until neutralization) to occur. Finally a spark is formed when the electric field strength exceeds the dielectric strength (polarizability of air) of air. The discharge in the conductive channel raises the temperature of the surrounding air. Since the discharge takes so little time to go from one region to another, the heated air has no time to expand. The heated air is compressed, raising the air's pressure to much higher values than the normal atmospheric pressure. The sudden expansion of the compressed air creates a loud burst, which we call a spark.

On [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_spark) there's also a good bit of explanation. Just google electric spark for further sources and explanations.

Comment: Sounds convincing. But considering that the charge acquired is very small, how can it produce a sound. Like, I do get that the sound is feeble, but does this sparking also occur in objects whose charges are small?

Comment: For it to occur the electric field strength has to exceed the dielectric strength of air. And for us to be able to hear, you can get a rough estimate for it by using $I_{sound wave} = p v$, where $p$ is the pressure of the air (compressed to much higher values than atmospheric pressure) and v the speed of air molecules. Of course this is of interest once the frequency does reach our ear sensitivity. In a lightning, the temperatures reach up to 30000 K, so very high pressures, hence the very loud sound we hear.

Comment: I know this thing, and I guess you missed the Laplace correction ;). Thanks for your answer!